# Android: changing alert dialog input type

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently doing some android development and was trying to find out if there is anyway of changing the input type in an alertbox?

at the moment i guess its just a standard text input box but i wanted to change it to a numeric input box so the soft keyboard changes to show the number pad. similar to how the `android:inputType="phone"` works in the xml layout side of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setView` in the `AlertDialog` class to add any view you like. You can then just change the `setInputType` to allow numbers only.

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_help);
alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
alertDialog.setView(input);
alertDialog.setButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Value of EditText
        String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
    }
});

alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dialog instead, then you can play around with stuff all you like :)

The basics:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.id.your_layout);
    EditText button = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.your_editText);
    dialog.show();
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution, no custom layouts needed.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
EditText dialogEditText = new EditText(this);
dialogEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your title");
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Your message");
alertDialogBuilder.setView(edittext);
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```